# UISearchBar solid color

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I would like to have a UISearchBar with a solid color rather than a gradient.

I have this:

```
UISearchBar *mySearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.bounds];
[mySearchBar sizeToFit];
mySearchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
mySearchBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.976 green:0.489 blue:0.0824 alpha:1.0];
```

And it gives me a gradient.  How can I make it a solid color?

Answer (score 3):

If you are targeting iOS 5.0 or later, you can use the UISearchBar [`backgroundImage`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) property:

> Images that are 1 point wide or stretchable images are stretched,
>   otherwise the image is tiled.

You can also set this property on the UISearchBar appearance proxy so that it will apply to all search bars throughout your app:

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:anImage];
```

Comment: Note that if you are showing the Scope Buttons on your search bar, you'll probably want to theme those as well:  

[[UISearchBar appearance] setScopeBarBackgroundImage:anImage];

Comment: If you want a _truly_ solid color, using this solution with a 1x1 solid colour image works. If you use barTintColor, you'll end up with a subtle gradient on top of whatever colour you select

Answer (score 1):

The color is used to 'tint' the bar, you can't use a solid.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7, you can set the `barTintColor` property of the `UISearchBar`.  This applies to the bar as well as scope buttons if you have them on your search bar.

```
searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Or, use the appearance proxy to apply throughout the app:

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```