# How to apply a solid color to a UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

I saw this post on SO: [UISearchBar solid color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232016/uisearchbar-solid-color)

But no answer was provided.

I would like to know how to apply a solid color to a UISearchBar. I have applied a tintColor but it automatically creates a gradient.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can override the drawRect for the search bar. By Setting the "UISearchBarBackground" view to an alpha of 0, it will paint it the flat tint color you set. For example, in your App Delegate add this:

```
@implementation UISearchBar( CustomBackground )
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Find the UISearchBarBackground view and set it's alpha to 0 so we get a "flat"
    // search bar.
    for( UIView *subview in self.subviews )
    {
        if( [subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString( @"UISearchBarBackground" )] )
        {
            [subview setAlpha:0.0F];
            break;
        }
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: Adding this causes my search bar background to be black instead of the color I'm trying to apply.  Any ideas why?

Comment: I also needed to change the backgroundcolor of the search bar, that gives the desired solid color on UISearchBar, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
        _tempSearchBar =[[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(44, 0, 320 - 44, 43)];
        _tempSearchBar.barStyle=UIBarStyleDefault;
        _tempSearchBar.placeholder=@"搜索";
        for( UIView *subview in _tempSearchBar.subviews )
        {
            if( [subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString( @"UISearchBarBackground" )] )
            {
                UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:subview.bounds];
                aView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
//                [subview setAlpha:0.0f];
                [subview addSubview:aView];
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
[toolbar setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

And got this:

[alt text http://gallery.me.com/davedelong/100084/Screen%20shot%202010-08-16%20at%202.44.07%20PM/web.png?ver=12819951050001](http://gallery.me.com/davedelong/100084/Screen%20shot%202010-08-16%20at%202.44.07%20PM/web.png?ver=12819951050001)

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I have not tried on code, but on IB setting the tint color works fine (But does not solve the solid color issue, there is still a gradient layer)