# iOS: How to replace Search Bar background shine/glow with one color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uisearchbar, searchbar

How do I remove the shine/glow (gradient) from the background of a Search Bar. I would like to replace it with just one color.

From this:

[image]

To something like this

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a background image?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
searchbar.backgroundImage = //your image here
```

and you can use a nifty category that I created for uiimage that will generate an image based on a color

https://github.com/Hackmodford/HMUIImage-imageWithColor

So all together it will look like this

```
searchBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

That will generate the effect you want.

Answer (score 1):

**1 To remove the glossy background:**

UISearchBar has a subview of class **UISearchBarBackground**, just cycle through the subviews and when you find a subview of that class, set its alpha to 0.

RubyMotion example:

```
searchBar.subviews.each { |v| v.alpha = 0 if v.class == UISearchBarBackground }
```

**2 To add a solid background override the drawRect method:**

RubyMotion example:

```
def drawRect(rect)
  blackColor = '#222222'.to_color
  context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
  CGContextSetFillColor(context, CGColorGetComponents(blackColor.CGColor))
  CGContextFillRect(context, rect)      
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont think you can, tried it myself and it seems to be part of the API, heres a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232016/uisearchbar-solid-color) that asks the same thing
The reason the FB one is a solid colour is because afaik the FB app use the Three20 framework. But even with all their scaling down its still a raw 30 megs in size, extreme overkill for a search bar in your case

Dont even know if an image will work as you can't set the area around the bar itself to be clear or transparent to put an image under it

Comment: But the facebook application is only like 6MB in size?

Comment: When you convert your app for uploading to the store it'll shrink a lot. An app i was working on for a company was several hundred megs due to Three20 and a load of images, to download it's about 8mbs